# Linear transformations performed on a coordinate grid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, transformation

Is it possible to graphically represent linear transformations in MATLAB like the one shown below?

[image: Graph Transformation Example]

In particular, I'm looking for a way to represent the way a coordinate grid might become squished, stretched, or rotated after a matrix multiplication has been performed. I've tried using `meshgrid(x,y)` to plot the grid but I've been having trouble getting it to display properly. Ideally, it would be nice to see the way that the transformation acts on a unit square (and, if possible, to see the transformation being performed in a continuous fashion, where you can see the graphs morphing into each other). However, I'm willing to sacrifice these last two requirements.

Here is the code I have used so far:

```
x = -10:2:10;
y = -10:2:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
plot(X,Y)
```

For some reason, only vertical lines have been plotted. (The [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) says it will display a *square* grid.)

[image: Vertical lines]

Answer (score 2):

please read the `plot` [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot&s_tid=srchtitle).
the problem is that what you are doing is trying to plot mash matrixes in a plot not by using mesh or something like that.

you may find [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93339-how-can-i-generate-a-2d-grid-plot-my-data) very helpful.